# How to validate an EditText when i enter Special charecters

Tags: android

I have three Edit Texts.
First EditText Name with out Special characters.when i enter any special character.I want to show a Error don't enter any special characters.
When i leave 2nd Edit Text my cursor in Third Edit Text.I want to show an red color border Edit text.

Comment: What you want only text or alphanumeric?

Comment: Hi Vishalk,i want to enter only text when i enter any special characters.i want to show red color border Edit Text

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160989/how-to-detect-special-characters-in-an-edit-text-and-display-a-toast-in-response

It might help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to show how to validate EditText input by user and update view border accordingly.

First of all implement and attach a TextWater to your EditView like this:

The activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    // Attach TextWatcher
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            // A-Z, a-z, space
            String pattern = "^([a-zA-Z ]*)$";

            // Check for pattern match
            if (!editable.toString().matches(pattern)) {

                // Set red border 
                editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_border);
            } else {

                // Restore default border
                editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_border);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Two drawable files used to draw border around EditText

/res/drawable/grey_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

/res/drawable/grey_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

And finally the layout file:

/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_border"
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
```

use the above line in edittext in xml file so that it only enters the alphabets and numbers only

or

Add textwatcher in edittext

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           // Here you need to check special character, if found then show error message

          if (s.toString().contains("%"))
          {
               // Display error message
          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions to check input. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provide documentation and describe patterns which you may use.

For your case, if you want to use only text characters you do:

```
public boolean isValid(String editTextInput){
     boolean isInputValid = false;

     String expression = "^[a-zA-Z]";
     CharSequence inputStr = editTextInput;

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
     if (matcher.matches()) {
          isInputValid = true;
     }
     return isInputValid ;
}
```

You can use this method right away. When you need to check input just place this code:

```
if(isValid(editText.getText().toString().trim()){
    //valid
}else{
    editText.setError("Can contain only text");
    editText.setText("");
}
```

If you want to check it right away when user made new input, so you have to implement `interface` `TextWatcher` and set it to your `EditText`. Example:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int count){}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int count) {}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if(isValid(editText.getText().toString().trim()){
        //valid
    }else{
        editText.setError("Only alphabet characters allowed");
        editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Also nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add TextWatcher to your EditText and apply the condition of recognizing special characters (when entered) and then you can set this inside the condition

```
editText.setError("You cannot use Special Characters");
```